# Python module for multiple variable global optimization

Tags: python, numpy, scientific-computing

I have been looking for a python module that implements the [common techniques](http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~neum/glopt/software_g.html) of global optimization (finding the global minimum of a function in N dimensions) without success.

If you heard about a simulated annealing or genetic algorithm implementation in python, please share.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Scipy's [optimize](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.html) module has a [`dual_annealing`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.dual_annealing.html?highlight=anneal#scipy.optimize.dual_annealing) function that might fit your needs. Also, you should check out the [PyEvolve](http://pyevolve.sourceforge.net/) module for doing a genetic algorithm.

Comment: anneal is deprecated in scipy: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.anneal.html#scipy.optimize.anneal

Comment: use basinhopping instead

Answer (score 7):

I'm not an expert, but have you looked at:

- Scipy's optimize: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.html#global
- NLOpt: http://ab-initio.mit.edu/wiki/index.php/NLopt_Introduction
- OpenOpt: http://openopt.org/Foreword

Answer (score 6):

One of the most common is [scipy.optimize](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.html).

For genetic algorithms, there's [pygene](http://www.freenet.org.nz/python/pygene/).

Also, the [aima-python](http://code.google.com/p/aima-python/) project has implementations of algorithms described in Russell and Norvig's "Artificial Intelligence: A Modern Approach".

Answer (score 1):

I've been working on a detailed comparison of many python global optimizers (I assume you are interested in derivative-free optimization where there are plenty of local minima).

- hyperopt
- optuna
- pysot
- scipy.optimize
- pymoo
- many more (see [list of some I left out](https://github.com/microprediction/tuneup/issues/1))

To summarize, I'd recommend scipy.optimize and if you're in dimension less than say ten, the SHGO algorithm therein is really solid. You might want to read up on it if you have a passing interest in homology. It is better than some previous ones, such as basin-hopping, because it cleverly tries to avoid redundant local searches.

The full list and comparisons are in the [report](https://www.microprediction.com/blog/optimize)

Answer (score 1):

**Simulated Annealing:**

[frigidum](https://pypi.org/project/frigidum/) is a python package for simulated annealing.